# Move/Copy unique rows from TableA to TableB, if they are not in TableB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, select, except

I'm required to move every unique row from `TableA` to `TableB`, if the unique row from `TableA` is not already in `TableB`.

Both tables look the same, they don't have any `key`s, but there's a combination of columns that make their rows unique for my task - `num` which is an `int` and `com`, a `varbinary(512)`.

As my SQL is horrible I wanted to create a script that does the job, but I have ridiculous problems, escaping/handling the `varbinary` value. This is why I'm asking for help.

I can pseudo-code..

moving/copying::

```
SELECT * INTO TableB
WHERE (unique TableA.num + TableA.com)
AND NOT IN (TableB)
FROM TableA
```

afterwards, for moving only

```
DELETE FROM TableA WHERE (unique from above)
```

(Working on Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition v9.00.3042.00, i.e. SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2)

**Additional details**

Sorry. I'm still learning SQL ***AND*** asking proper questions..

`TableA` & `TableB` have the same design. They have multiple columns, including the two above mentioned ones. I'm required to both move and copy (depending on the chosen option). `TableA` is the source, `TableB` is the destination. Both tables may contain numerous occurrences of the same int/com combination. I need to have only one (it doesn't matter which one) of each of the combinations. With copying they're not removed from `TableA`, when moving, they should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I can understand correctly what you are looking to do, you want to `SELECT` all records from `TableA` that only appear once, but don't already appear in `TableB`.

You can do this with a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to identify those that only appear once in `TableA`, then do an `EXCEPT` to filter out those that already appear in `TableB`.

```
SELECT
  int,
  com
FROM TableA
GROUP BY int, com
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1

EXCEPT 

SELECT
  int,
  com
FROM TableB
```

If you actually wanted to `SELECT` **ALL** distinct records from `TableA` (regardless of how many times they occur in `TableA`) that do not already appear in `TableB`, <del>then you could use the `DISTINCT` keyword.</del>

**Edit:** As @ypercube correctly pointed out, `EXCEPT` already filters for `DISTINCT` rows

```
SELECT 
  int,
  com
FROM TableA

EXCEPT 

SELECT
  int,
  com
FROM TableB
```

---

If the two tables have more columns, it's handier to use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `EXCEPT`. You could also use `ROW_NUMBER()` to select an arbitrary row in 2005+ versions. So, the copying from table A to B would be:

```
INSERT INTO TableB
  (int, com, --- rest of the columns)
SELECT
  int, com, --- rest of the columns,
FROM
  ( SELECT
      int, com, --- rest of the columns,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY int, com ORDER BY someColumn)
    FROM 
      TableA AS a
    WHERE
      NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM TableB AS b
        WHERE b.int = a.int
          AND b.com = a.com
      ) 
  ) AS copy
WHERE 
    rn = 1 ;
```